# How to change non-default constructor in fragments to default constructor?

Tags: java, android

Code:

```
public PlacePickerFragment() {
    this(null);
}
public PlacePickerFragment(Bundle args) {
    super(GraphPlace.class, R.layout.com_facebook_placepickerfragment, args);
    setPlacePickerSettingsFromBundle(args);
}
```

Hello, I want to remove deprecation warning from code above, is there a way changed it to default constructor?

Comment: Which line has the deprecation warning?

Comment: According to java doc at [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html), Fragment only has an empty constructor. So where does your super(GraphPlace.class, R.layout.com_facebook_placepickerfragment, args) come from?

Comment: Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead

Comment: Line super(GraphPlace.class, R.layout.com_facebook_placepickerfragment, args); from facebook-sdk library

Comment: I can confirm this problem exists in the Facebook SDK 3.0. Annoying that they can't get things like this right. It's a full on error now so that causes problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your fragment, use setArgument():

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
// Construct your bundle here
Fragment mFragment = new PlacePickerFragment();
mFragment.setArguments(args);
mFragment.initialize();
```

And use fragment's default constructor. You may need to call `setPlacePickerSettingsFromBundle()` after you have set the arguments, something like this:

```
public PlacePickerFragment() {
    super(GraphPlace.class, R.layout.com_facebook_placepickerfragment, args);
}

public void initialize() {
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    setPlacePickerSettingsFromBundle(args);
}
```

Comment: May I ask what is the "args" of your constructor ?

Comment: @RRTW Its a "Bundle" type object reference

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `Bundle` parameter and make the constructor take no arguments. Then use `setArguments()` to pass the bundle. If necessary, create static factory method to create your fragment with the necessary arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Lawrence Choy was very helpful, but did not work for me as the super() call do not accept the args variable. This worked for me:

```
public void initialize() {
  Bundle args = getArguments();
  setPlacePickerSettingsFromBundle(args);
}

/**
  * Default constructor. Creates a Fragment with all default properties.
  */
public PlacePickerFragment() {
  super(GraphPlace.class, R.layout.com_facebook_placepickerfragment, null);
}
```